# API to broadcast live webcam

Tags: flash, api, broadcast

I would like to know if anyone here knows an API where it's possible for me to create a live webcam broadcast from inside my website?

I was checking the uStream API and it seems that you can't create anything, just retrieve data... Does anyone knows anything like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Flash Media Server or Flash Comm Server and code in actionscript to connect to the server for live streaming. AS3 has got inbuilt support for web cam programming using Flash Communication Server/Media Server.

Answer (score 0):

See [Basics of video](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000252.html) at adobe.com