# developing a scalabe chat system

Tags: java, python, video-streaming, twisted, chat

I am a java developer and am pretty comfortable with develeoping webapps in java/jsp/servlets.

I want to develop a video **web based chat website**.people should be able to chat with each other using my website.People dont need to use any client app installed on their pc in order to chat with others.

My website should be scalable.It should be able to support many hundreds of  user simultaneously.I heard that there is a framework cal is beastled twisted matrix in python that best for developing such kind of servers.But learning a new language of me is not feasible as i dont have much time to get the system up and running.I have  2 months to get the application  up and running.

After googling i found that twisted matrix ix best for the puropose.

So what should i do?Should i go ahead with java or python?Which java framework to use?If i develop it in java should i develop a web app which will run on top of app server? or shold i develop my own chat server in java?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused: the requirement is that users don't need *any* software installed on their PC?  How can that be?  You need something.

Given two months, I think you only have two options:

1. [Flash](http://www.adobe.us/devnet/flash/articles/image_api_03.html)
2. [Skype](http://developer.skype.com/accessories)

Like you said, because you have two months to get it up and running, you're best off *not* learning a new language.  As far as Java network frameworks go, people seem to have pretty good experiences with [Netty](http://jboss.org/netty), [MINA](http://mina.apache.org/), or [Grizzly](https://grizzly.dev.java.net/), but going that low-level will probably cause you grief.

There's some good stuff on SO too:

- [API to broadcast live webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257364/api-to-broadcast-live-webcam)

Answer (score 1):

Just Try [Cometd](http://cometd.org/)， CometD is a scalable HTTP-based event routing bus that uses a Ajax Push technology pattern known as Comet. There is also a chatroom example in the sourcecode.
Cometd is based on Jetty Continuation。
Using Long pooling.